# unnest string array in druid in ingestion phase for better rollup

Tags: druid

I am trying to define a druid ingestion spec for the following case.
I have a field of type *string array* and I want it to be unnested and rolled up by druid during the ingestion. For example, if I have the following two entries in the raw data:

```
["a","b","c"]
["a", "c"]
```

In the rollup table I would like to see three entries:

```
"a"  2
"b"  1
"c"  2
```

If I just define this column as a dimension, the array is kept as is and the individual values are not extracted. I've looked on possible solution with *transformSpec* and *Expressions*, by no help.
I know how to use *GROUP BY* in query time to get what I need, but I'd like to have this functionality during the ingestion time. Is there some way to define in in the *dataSchema*?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you use SQL Based Ingestion available since Apache Druid 24.0.0, you can do something like:

```
REPLACE INTO "inline_data" OVERWRITE ALL
WITH "ext" AS (SELECT *
FROM TABLE(
  EXTERN(
    '{"type":"inline","data":"{\"timestamp\":\"2023-01-01 00:00:00\", \"array_col\":[\"a\",\"b\",\"c\"], \"metric\":5},\n{\"timestamp\":\"2023-01-01 00:00:00\", \"array_col\":[\"b\",\"c\",\"d\"], \"metric\":50},\n{\"timestamp\":\"2023-01-01 00:00:00\", \"array_col\":[\"e\",\"f\",\"d\"], \"metric\":500}"}',
    '{"type":"json"}'
  )
) EXTEND ("timestamp" VARCHAR, "array_col" VARCHAR, "metric" BIGINT))
SELECT
  TIME_PARSE(TRIM("timestamp")) AS "__time",
  "array_col" as "array_col",
  SUM("metric") AS "sum_metric"
FROM "ext"
GROUP BY 1,2
PARTITIONED BY DAY
```

You will also need to set the query context parameter `groupByEnableMultiValueUnnesting:true`